# Searching Pages and custom models at the same time in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-search

I made a blunder - implemented some models in our application as plain Django models (but Indexable) instead of Page models.

Now the client would like to see a unified search results page (so a faceted search is not adequate)... so I am completely stuck.

We are using the PostgreSQL backend. The s.search() function requires a model or queryset; and you cannot combine PostgresSearchResults query sets. If I convert the 2 result sets to list and combine them I lose the relevancy of the results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of rendering non-homogenuous search results, you can use:

`from itertools import chain`

And let's say you've searched pages, documents, images, and also have some other results - you can do this (including pagination since you'll need that too):

```
page_results = SOME PAGE RESULTS
doc_results = docs_to_search.search(search_query, order_by_relevance=False)
img_results = images_to_search.search(search_query, order_by_relevance=False)
other_search_results = SOME RESULTS FROM SEARCHING MODELS

all_results = list(chain(other_search_results, page_results, img_results, doc_results))

# Pagination
paginator = Paginator(all_results, items_per_page, orphans=num_orphans)
try:
    results = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    results = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

and then return your `results` from your view and render in the template with `{% for result in results %}`

Comment: As a general result it is excellent - but we would like to keep the relevance based ordering, that's exactly why I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the pointer, I was able to solve it using the .annotate_score("_score") function in search queries and with all_results.sort(key=lambda x: x._score, reverse=True) - fortunately there will be only a few hunders records so that will do for now.